# Remove dots from XML tags

Tags: javascript, regex, xml

```
<a.b>
    <x.y>
        SomeData
    </x.y>
</a.b>
```

should become

```
<ab>
    <xy>
        SomeData
    </xy>
</ab>
```

What regex can be use to replace first xml string with second?

Answer (score 3):

Use `string.replace` function.

```
string.replace(/\.(?=[^<>]*>)/g, '')
```

`(?=[^<>]*>)` positive lookahead which asserts that the match must be followed by ,

- `[^<>]*` any char but not of `<` or `>`, zero or more times.
- `>` further followed by a `>` symbol.
- So this would match all the dots which are present inside angular brackets.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/zV3hT6/1)